# How To Add CSS/JS Dependencies To Phoenix Project?

Tags: jquery, elixir, phoenix-framework, brunch

I'm trying to add jquery to a Phoenix project.

When I link to jquery direct in app.html.eex in the head tag like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...It works.

However, I don't want a web dependency.  I want jquery within the app.

I've copied jquery.min.js to the web/static/js directory.  And referenced it in app.html.eex like so:

```
<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/jquery.min.js") %>"></script>
```

It doesn't work.

Copying jquery.min.js to app.js doesn't work either.

Interesting enough when I place the JS between script tags directly in app.html.eex, it works.

Only a direct link from the cloud and/or placing the JS between a script tag in app.html.eex is working??

Update:

Brunch is copying the JS to app.js in the priv directory.  But the application doesn't seem to have access to it.

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 17):

We recommend you to put vendor dependencies inside "web/static/vendor" because those dependencies are often not in ES6 nor work with JS loaders. Also, when you add them to vendor, they will be automatically added to the built `app.js` by brunch.

Alternatively, you can follow Dmitry's feedback. In this case, you can place the file inside "web/static/assets" and it will be copied as is to your application. For example, by putting it at "web/static/assets/js/jquery-min.js", the script tag you have defined in your post should work.

#### Update

After studying the sample repository given in the comments, the bug seems to be in the ordering: bootstrap is being included in the app.js file before jquery. You can fix this by adding the following to your brunch-config.js (a similar sample is already commented in there):

```
  order: {
    before: [
      "web/static/vendor/js/jquery.min.js",
      "web/static/vendor/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"
    ]
  }
```

I have to agree this is not obvious. Alternative solutions:

1. Order them in your vendor directory, for example: 1_jquery.min.js, 2_bootstrap-toggle.min.js, etc.
2. Move the files to "web/static/assets/js/jquery-min.js" and so on and add explicit script tags for them in your pages

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks.  I must be missing something somewhere though.  I've added the js to the vendor folder.  Then run node node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch build.  The js shows compiled in priv/static/js, yet it doesn't seem to work in the app.  However direct web links to the js in app.html.eex do work.  What might cause this?  Any ideas for a fix?

Comment: Do you have an application on GitHub that shows the issue? I would gladly take a look. :)

Comment: To be clear, if you are using vendor, you still need this line in your layout: `<script src="<%= static_path(@conn, "/js/app.js") %>"></script>`

Comment: Big thanks. Heres the github: http://github.com/makeitgreat/phoenix_a_b_test If you navigate to: localhost:4000/test_a.html & localhost:4000/test_b.html you can see the bug. test_b.html.eex has the external css & JS links. test_a.html.eex doesn’t. JS & CSS show in priv directory app.js & app.css

Comment: Ok, I solved it. It was an ordering issue! I have updated the answer.

Comment: Hi, I am very new to phoenix(as today is my second day) I want to add jquery.js library to my application and I followed above steps and I still get $ is not defined.... 

I even cloned the above github-link ( github.com/makeitgreat/phoenix_a_b_test and still getting same error... Please help me with this part as I already lost 2 days to figure out

Comment: @KJ_kaka if you build a new phoenix application and just drop jquery (nothing more) inside web/static/vendor/js, it should just work. If you are dropping other dependencies that depend on js, you may need to order them in your brunch-config.js file. Also, make sure that when you run `mix phoenix.server` there are no warnings or errors in the terminal. If there are, please open up a new question with them. :)

Comment: @JoseValim I followed these steps. 1) mix phoenix.new inceptionApp --database mysql, 2) cd inceptionApp/, 3) gave username credentials ,4) mix ecto.create 5)mix ecto.migrate and then downloaded jquery.js file and placed it in this folder web/static/vendor/js and then I started server 6)mix phoenix.server and still i get same error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'  and here is my repo https://github.com/vikasd02/incApp

Comment: You have two jquery entries web/static/vendor/js in there. Why?

Answer (score 12):

While copying libraries to static works, I don't like it at all, because it trashes `git log` a lot for every update of every JS library, especially a big one.

Fortunately, Phoenix has official support for adding JS libs via npm/Brunch and it is present in the documentation: [Static Assets - Javascript Libraries](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/static-assets#section-javascript-libraries).

This is how I've added `jQuery` into my application:

**NOTE: This is for Phoenix 1.3, see instructions for 1.4 below**

Added `jquery` with a version number to dependencies section of `package.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "jquery": "3.2.1"
  }
}
```

Performed install:

```
npm install --save
```

Added globals into `npm` section of `brunch-config.js`:

```
npm: {
  enabled: true,
  globals: {
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  }
}
```

After app restart, I was able to use `$`.

**UPDATE for Phoenix 1.4**

Phoenix 1.4 switched from Brunch to Webpack.

*assets/package.json*

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "jquery": "3.3.1"
  }
}
```

*assets/webpack.config.js*

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
...
  plugins: [
  ...
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: "jquery",
      jQuery: "jquery"
    })
  ]
```

*assets/js/app.js* (this one is optional, but is required to make **$** available in Chrome console)

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
```

Run

```
(cd assets && npm install)
```

and restart Phoenix application.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Currently you may need to type `$: 'jQuery', jQuery: 'jQuery'` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the Phoenix 1.4 update!! This is the first mention of non-Brunch I've come across. Otherwise I'd still be cherry picking through my directory searching for the non-existent "brunch-config.js" file. Sheesh.

Comment: BTW: I don't have "assets/app.js" in my Phoenix 1.4 project. Do you mean "assets/js/app.js"?

Answer (score 4):

Dependencies in Phoenix are managed by [Brunch.io](http://brunch.io/).
By default it copies everything from `/web/static/assets/` directory to `/priv/static`.

So you can simply create some directory like `plugins` inside `/web/static/assets/` and copy `jquery.min.js` there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to post a comment to the answer from @denis.peplin (in which the link is outdated). But it seems this is the official post referred to (again there is a Javascript Libraries section)...

[phoenixframework-blog-static-assets](http://phoenixframework.org/blog/static-assets)

In my case the following worked:

Add the dependency to `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
  "jquery": "3.2.1"
},
```

Then in `assets/js/app.js` add the following line...

```
import $ from "jquery"
```