# How to add jquery to phoenix 1.3 using npm

Tags: jquery, elixir, phoenix-framework

There are [good official phoenix docs](http://phoenixframework.org/blog/static-assets) explaining how to add an npm dependency (even uses jquery). Evidently, I am missing something here. Here is what I have:

Using `elixir 1.6`, `phoenix 1.3`, and `node 8.9` on Mac OSX.

**assets/js/app.js** contains:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
```

**assets/brunch-config.js** contains:

```
 npm: {
    enabled: true,
    npm: {
      globals: {
        $: 'jquery',
        jQuery: 'jquery'
      }
    }
  }
```

**package.json** contains:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "phoenix": "file:../deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:../deps/phoenix_html"
  }
```

My "application logic" - in a js file imported from **assets/js/app.js**:

```
$(function () {
  alert('Hello');
});
```

Do have a workaround by simply (manually) copying `jquery.min.js` from `assets/node_modules/query/dist` into `assets/vendor`. But am keen to understand what is going wrong with the automatic inclusion using `npm` and brunch asset pipeline.

Comment: And what's the problem? Do you get some error?

Comment: Are you loading the generated `public/app.js` file in your views? Example: https://github.com/phoenix-examples/hello_phoenix/blob/master/web/templates/layout/app.html.eex

Comment: Yes, I am - as above, the jquery function etc all loads into browser. $ is not recognised unless i also add jquery.mins.js to vendor. Otherwise app.js is loading as expected.

Comment: @Dogbert - the problem is that $ is not recognised. It seems that doing the above (as per official phoenix docs) still isn't enough to successfully load jquery (and find $ on window object (global).

Comment: Do hesitate to rebuke official docs so apologies in advance if there is some kind of oversight on my part. Hoping I just overlooked something.

Comment: Anyone have a working sample on github using NPM and jquery dependency? Be interested to do a comparison.

Comment: Can you try adding `import $ from 'jquery';` to the file which uses `$`?

Comment: @Dogbert - fyi only - this is the github repo - https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-elixir-single-page-app

Comment: Shall try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `import $ from 'jquery';` in app.js

In `assets/brunch-config.js` do this instead:

```
npm: {
  enabled: true,
  globals: {
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  }
}
```

(you have extra `npm` section inside top `npm` section)

I've answered similar question before, still actual: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43265955/1173020