# Import node modules from priv/static/js folder in Phoenix 1.4

Tags: javascript, webpack, elixir, phoenix-framework, node-modules

I installed vuejs with a `npm install` in my assets/ folder and I created a list_show.js file in priv/static/js/list_show.js . When I do `import Vue from "vue"` in my list_show.js, it doesn't work and I get this message in the console: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".

How can I import modules in my static/js/ folder? (I'm using Phoenix 1.4 and Webpack by default)

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43265955/1173020
It's not about Vue, but it shouldn't be a big problem to add Vue too.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how I can add vueJS with your answer. Also, I don't think it would be practical to always call "webpack.ProvidePlugin" for every single node modules I'm installing.

Comment: are you using babel with webpack, or how are you transpiling the es6 syntax?

Comment: I'm using the basic configuration of Phoenix 1.4. Meaning webpack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not create your `.js` files in the `/priv/static/js` directory. Instead, use the `/assets` directory.

Phoenix 1.4 uses Webpack to bundle `js` files located in `/assets` into a single `app.js` file which will be placed into `/priv/static/js`. As an entry point to your application, you can use `/assets/js/app.js` where the following lines load Vue:

```
import Vue from 'vue';

new Vue({
  // ...
});
```

(You can also put this code in a seperate `.js` file, as long as you import it in `app.js`)

This solution, however, won't help if you need static js files for different routes. You maybe want to always render `priv/static/js/app.js`, but specific files just on specific layouts. Achieving multiple output files in `priv/static/js` can be done by modifying your `webpack.config.js` slightly and adding more entrypoints:

```
entry: {
  app: ['./js/app.js'].concat(glob.sync('./vendor/**/*.js')),
  special: ['./js/special.js']
},
output: {
  filename: '[name].js',
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../priv/static/js')},
}
```

With this config, two files will be created:

- `priv/static/js/app.js` - Containing all vendor files and `app.js`
- `priv/static/js/special.js` - Containing just `special.js`

The `special.js` file can be included within Phoenix then:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Routes.static_path(@conn, "/js/special.js") %>"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you ! This was exactly what I needed to do ! :D